# How to customize dropzone area in DropzoneJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, dropzone.js, dropzone

This is current behavior:

[image: currently displaying like this]

I need to customize the height of the dropzone area like bellow.

[image: Target display is with height]

How can I customize the height and width of this dropzone area?
I have no clue to solve it. please help.

Comment: Use CSS to amend the styling of the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using something like:

```
<div id="dropzone-file-upload" class="dropzone" style="height:200px"></div>
```

Or create a CSS class if you need to do height and width to make the HTML easier to read.

I will warn you though that this doesn't scale the thumbnails of the files uploaded. I suggest you either add a `zoom: x` or look at https://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration-options for `thumbnailWidth` and `thumbnailHeight` to be defined in your JavaScript